# git Flow and merging strategy

Tags: git, merge, branch, pull

In my team we follow a Git branching strategy, like given below

```
   master
       release 
         develop
           feature1
           feature2
```

Let's say I work on a feature (feature1) and by the time I'm done several hundred commits have gone to develop because my feature is so big. In order to be in sync with develop branch and not incur a huge merge effort later, I merge changes from develop to my feature branch often. So when I'm done, my feature branch would actually be more current than the develop with all commits from all other developers besides my own feature development.

The question now is,

1. Am I doing the right thing by merging develop branch to feature branch often during my development time? The reason I'm asking is, I will anyway need to do another merge to develop branch (from my feature branch when I'm done) so the merges I have been doing all along (from develop to feature) is a waste of effort. I did these just so to ensure I stay close to develop.
2. When I'm done with my feature, because my feature branch is more current than anything in the repo, I could simply make it the new develop, can't I? this will save me from dong another merge (to develop). If I were to do it though, it's going to impact all other developers who have been tracking the real develop branch. If I just delete the develop branch and then rename my feature as develop and move it to the remote, would it solve this problem?

Comment: *"Let's say I work on a feature... and by the time I'm done several hundred commits have gone to develop because my feature is so big"* - I think *that's* the core problem - can you break your tasks down into smaller steps that can be delivered and integrated more frequently?

Comment: @jonrsharpe sure. that's an option but I wondered what is the right thing to do in case my feature branch takes twice as long as the other's feature. It could also be that I have several hundred developers making commits and my feature is almost the same size as the rest of the team.

Comment: Well, *is* that the scenario you're in? Again that sounds like a problem that changing your merging strategy doesn't actually help solve.

Comment: If you need to work on your feature branch for an extended period of time, and there is a lot of changes being introduced on develop in the meantime, you can choose between merging often into your feature branch, to handle merge conflicts while they're both small in size and fresh in the minds of those who have made them, or to merge once at the end, which could become a big merge conflict. To me, merging often would not be a waste of time.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @Lasse V. Karlsen